# Why don't raytracing algorithms include the speed of light?

Tags: raycasting, raytracing

From what I understand about ray-tracing, it is instantaneous in its speed from the light source to the user. Is there a type of ray-tracing where the "rays" move at the speed of light or are affected by gravity? Such methods would be useful in simulating large scale systems (like planets).

Also, can the same method be applied to sound?

Comment: From what I know of raytracing, it is not meant to be a physics simulation for realism, but it's just a different technique that gives more realistic results, at the expense of performance. If you want your plants to have a specific look, you can simulate that yourself with raytracing.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I asked

Comment: Sure. The rendering of the black hole in Interstellar famously involved physically accurate (or at least physically inspired) simulation of light bending around the gravity source. No law would be broken by applying the idea to sound. How have you tried applying this in your game so far, and what step in the process do you need help with?

Comment: I've tried some testing in a new project (with sound in particular, although I'm only at the ray casting stage). My problem is not something related to this question, but that I'm having trouble getting the rays to go through objects (so they move to the edge of an object once they are inside) without making each ray resource-intensive.

Comment: @DMGregory I realised how ambiguous my question is. I guess it is not so hard to adapt an existing solution into a solution where the rays propagate at the speed of the light by limiting its distance travelled in a given time frame.

Comment: Raytracing follows single rays from the camera. If you want to "bend light" you would need to specify that rays simply scatter around heavy objects, similar to how refraction works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible to create a raytracing renderer which does this.

You would just need to know the delta-time of the frame you are calculating (time since last frame) and keep track of the distance each ray traveled (which you often do anyway in order to implement certain effects). When the distance traveled exceeds the distance light is able to travel in the current delta-time timeframe, you simply store the current data of the ray in some data-structure and continue computing it the next frame.

You might need some more memory and you might have to calculate a couple more rays per frame, but there are a lot of quality tradeoffs you can make in raytracing to get down to what your target platform can manage.

But the question is if there is a use-case for this feature.

Most games take place on scales where the speed of light isn't relevant. You would need a game which takes place on astronomic scales for the speed of light to have any observable effects. But most games of that kind take place in science fiction scenarios where the speed of light is conveniently ignored anyway for narrative reasons.

Comment: One wrinkle to raise here is time. The further out we look, the older the image we see. So if objects move fast enough for the speed of light observing them to be relevant, you may need to adjust your rays to test against past locations, if firing from the camera. It's tempting to just track waves of rays "in flight," each testing against only the current moment but taking multiple frames to reach the viewer, but this is challenging if the camera can move — now you need many more rays to be able to catch the various places we might be viewing from by the time the wave of rays arrives.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In reference to a suitable use-case, I'm interest in the mechanics of light (like wavelength shifting, gravitational lensing), so this sort of stuff would be cool to see implemented. It would also be interesting changing the properties like speed to create different effects. Or for an interesting game? I'll look into and try creating an engine like this :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question here since I realise the ambiguity of the original question.

It is not impossible in theory to adapt an existing ray-tracing solution so that the rays are limited in distance.

For example, for a simulation at 60 frames per second, a ray of light would travel a maximum of `c/60` *(in a vacuum)* every frame. However, in a simulation with many objects, if the light would need to reflect multiple times before reaching the distance required, it will be computationally intensive to run at close to real time (so a break out value will be needed).

The same solution can be adapted for sound or another wave at a specific speed.